# Align y origins in two y-axis charts using Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

[image]

I created two charts in one window using both plotyy and yyaxis. Is there any option I can set to have the zero of both axis aligned? See attached screenshot.

Here is my code:

```
yyaxis left
plot(x,y1)
yyaxis right
plot(x,y2)
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to actually add the picture you mentioned...

Comment: yes. I added it

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/37821-plotyy-how-to-make-yaxis-align-at-zero

Comment: @jgrant plotyy is not suggest anymore in recent versions of MATLAB.